# Can an object returned from another application domain be serialized in calling domain?

Tags: c#, serialization, appdomain, remoting, datacontractjsonserializer

In the following code, when the`SerializeToJson()` method is called, I receive the following exception on `WriteObject()` :

> Remoting cannot find field '__identity' on type 'System.MarshalByRefObject'

Is what i'm attempting to do possible? I'm a little unfamiliar with Application Domains and their related things (transparent proxy, etc.). I can serialize my TestClass in the current application domain successfully, but I don't understand why it's not working here. Thanks for looking.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public class BaseClass : MarshalByRefObject { }
    public class RemoteClass : BaseClass
    {
        public TestClass DoIt()
        {
            return new TestClass { Prop1 = DateTime.Now, Prop2 = 1234 };
        } 
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TestClass : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public TestClass() { }
        public TestClass(TestClass tc)
        {
            Prop1 = tc.Prop1;
            Prop2 = tc.Prop2;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Prop1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myappdomain");
            var remoteClass = (RemoteClass)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(RemoteClass).FullName);
            var returnedTestClass = remoteClass.DoIt();

            Console.WriteLine(SerializeToJson(returnedTestClass));
        }

        private static string SerializeToJson(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
                    serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Error: Remoting cannot find field '__identity' on type 'System.MarshalByRefObject'.
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with *Protobuf*:

https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net

However, I would warn that based on the usage of [DataContract], this smells like WCF, which is usually a one-way road. WCF is notorious for dictating to you how you should write your application - and this includes serialization.

That being said, I've never had issues with JSON.Net for serializing classes marked with [DataContract].  JsonConvert.Serialize() works against System.Object.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to mix `[DataContract]` with `MarshalByRefObject` for .NET *Remoting*.  Just use `MarshalByRefObject` like you did with `RemoteClass`